# best practices in detecting relay contacts status

Tags: microcontroller, interface, latching-relay

Currently i'm experimenting with 12VDC energy meters latching relays and at least for me the feature of detecting status of contacts ( required by some clients ) which is built in as in the diagram below is quite interesting. Now i need to interface it to a microcontroller safely. At the top of my head i may think of using an optocoupler but my understanding is i need to isolate the grounds ? thus making the design a bit pain in the kneck, is this the only feasible method or are there other approaches ?. 
[image]

TL;DR pins 4 and 5 switch on / off depeding on status of relay, how do i sense/ measure status of the latch with those pins?

Comment: Could you narrow down what you have in mind? The simplest thing would be to use a comparator circuit to see if the voltages are the similar. A more complex expensive thing would to send a RF coupled signal and then detect with a lock in amplifier.

Comment: I edited the post please tell me if that is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Auxiliary contacts are not currently used, you just connect them to a microcontroller digital input as you would any other switch - something like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faGKyZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the auxiliary contact is already used, you may have to use an opto-coupler or perhaps an additional relay, depending on what is connected to the auxiliary contacts of the contactor.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by "used" , the pins are not connected to anything (4,5) but are effected by the coills when they are activated/deactivated. Assuming i connect pin 4 with my digital ground, this is considered safe to the mcu pins right?

Comment: By "used" I meant "currently connected to something".  If the auxiliary contacts are not connected to anything now, you can use them as my schematic shows.